# Sorting on atomic element of denormalized array with mongodb aggregate request

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate, denormalization

I have this following data in my Characters collection :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 110 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 50 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 200 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "type": "archer",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "precision", "value": 70 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 80 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 150 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 80 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 80 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 220 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "type": "wizard",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "power", "value": 100 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 100 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 120 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5",
        "type": "monk",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 50 },
            { "name": "intelligence", "value": 120 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 180 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 90 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 75 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 200 }
        ]
    }
]
```

NB: "attributes" is a denormalized array of object (name + value) in my model.

I write a generic service to allow users to filter my data. This service builds my "aggregate" query dynamically according to user input (selection, conditions, sorting, etc.).

I wish to return all the warriors ordered by descending id. The generated query will be:

```
Characters.aggregate().match({ "type": "warrior" }).sort({ "_id": -1 });
```

Expected results :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 90 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 75 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 200 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 80 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 80 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 220 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 110 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 50 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 200 }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I would like to display the list of warriors ordered by ascending strength. I can't sort on a specific element of my denormalized array "attributes" and this is my problem.

Expected results :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 80 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 80 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 220 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 90 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 75 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 200 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "type": "warrior",
        "attributes": [
            { "name": "strength", "value": 110 },
            { "name": "dexterity", "value": 50 },
            { "name": "health", "value": 200 }
        ]
    }
]
```

How should I proceed to get this result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'type': 'warrior'
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            "strength": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$attributes",
                    as: "attr",
                    cond: {$eq: [ "$$attr.name", "strength"] } 
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$sort': { "strength": 1 }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'strength': 0
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't understand this request ...

How do you make it clear that the sort is done on the attribute "strength" rather than another one ? "strength" isn't always the first attribute of the array.